# Dividir valor com numeros aleatórios

Tags: php

Tenho um valor que preciso dividi-lo em partes não iguais com vários números.

ex: se eu receber o numero 100, poderia gerar 20,30,10,20, 5, 15 = 100

o problema é que meu código está errado, o programa trava, não sai do numero 2.

```
function separate($val) {
    if ($val == 1) {
        return "1";
    }
    $list = [];
    $total = 0;
    while (true) {
        $tmp = rand(1, $val);
        if ($tmp + $total == $val) {
            $list[] = $tmp;
            $total += $tmp;
            break;
        } else {
            $list[] = $tmp;
            $total += $tmp;
        }
    }
    return json_encode($list);
}

foreach (range(1, 500) as $m) { // gera ate 500 de prêmio
    print "{$m}\n";
    var_dump(separate($m));
    print "=======\n";
}
```

Comment: poderia gerar 20,30,10,20, 5, 15, mas não é  em partes não iguais? o 20 tá repetido. E em quantas partes seriam?

Comment: não precisa ser exatamente diferentes, acho que me expressei mal, pq se for tudo igual eu poderia dividir por um numero, mas tem q ter um pouco de aleatoriedade, sobre a quantidade de 1-12 no máximo. e os números precisam ser inteiros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simples alternativa para atender seu comentário**

> não precisa ser exatamente diferentes, acho que me expressei mal, pq se for tudo igual eu poderia dividir por um numero, mas tem q ter um pouco de aleatoriedade, sobre a quantidade de 1-12 no máximo. e os números precisam ser inteiros.
>
> ex: se eu receber o numero 100, poderia gerar 20,30,10,20, 5, 15 = 100

```
$numGrupos   = rand(1,12);
$soma               = 100;
$grupos             = array();
$grupo              = 0;

//array_sum() retorna a soma dos valores de um array.
while(array_sum($grupos) != $soma)
{
    $grupos[$grupo] = mt_rand(0, $soma/mt_rand(1,5));

    if(++$grupo == $numGrupos)
    {
        $grupo  = 0;
    }
}

$string = implode(',', $grupos);
```

[Teste on-line](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be2629a97763e9df7150e5727054302783c6051a)

Answer (score 1):

A razão é porque o loop está infinito, o que pode fazer é simplesmente subtrair o valor, até que atinja o zero.

```
<?php

function separate($val) {
    if ($val == 1) {
        return "1";
    }

    $list = [];

    while ($val > 0) {
        $val -= ($rand = rand(1, $val));
        $list[] = $rand;    
    }

    return json_encode($list);
}

foreach (range(1, 500) as $m) { // gera ate 500 de prêmio
    print $m . "->" . separate($m);
    print "=======<br>";
}
```

[Teste aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f9f68e1c304049af7b7409b9034d25e1b0d5b20)

O problema do seu código se resume em:

```
while (true) {
      $tmp = rand(1, $val);
      if ($tmp + $total == $val) {
```

Vamos supor que `$val = 100`. Portanto, o $tmp poderá ser de 1 até 100, digamos 50. Na próxima execução ele poderá ser denovo de 1 até 100, por exemplo 80. Então a sua comparação de $tmp + $total irá falhar, porque afinal temos 80+50 > 100. Quando ela falha tornará um loop infinito.

Para corrigir isto você tem que forçar a executa execução para ser limitado até 50, no caso do exemplo anterior. Então você pode usar `$tmp = rand(1, ($val - $total));`:

```
function separate($val) {
    if ($val == 1) {
        return "1";
    }
    $list = [];
    $total = 0;
    while (true) {
        $tmp = rand(1, ($val - $total); // Agora não tem como gerar um número  maior
        if ($tmp + $total == $val) {
            $list[] = $tmp;
            $total += $tmp;
            break;
        } else {
            $list[] = $tmp;
            $total += $tmp;
        }
    }
    return json_encode($list);
}

foreach (range(1, 500) as $m) { // gera ate 500 de prêmio
    print "{$m}\n";
    var_dump(separate($m));
    print "=======\n";
}
```

---

De todas as formas não vejo sentido em usar essa função, você pode simplesmente fazer usar o `random_int`, *que inclusive é mais seguro*.

Answer (score 1):

Implementei de um jeito simples que pode resolver seu problema:

```
<?php

$numeros = [];
$numeroAnalisado = 100;

$randomicoAuxiliar = $numeroAnalisado;

if($numeroAnalisado == 1) $numeros[] = 1;
else 
{
    for($randomicoAuxiliar = $numeroAnalisado; $randomicoAuxiliar >= 1;)
    {
        $valorRandomico = rand(1, $randomicoAuxiliar);
        $randomicoAuxiliar = $randomicoAuxiliar - $valorRandomico;
        $numeros[] = $valorRandomico;
    }

    foreach($numeros as $numero) 
    {
        echo $numero . "<br >";
    }
}

$soma = array_sum($numeros);
echo "<br />Soma: " . $soma;
```